# Is there a way to count how many people visited my site?

Tags: javascript, web, click, html

Is it possible to find out, how many people have visited your website?

I am looking for solution using `Javascript` or `HTML`.

If the user is on my website, it should count +1.

I have no idea and have not tried anything yet.

Comment: Check out [Google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't possibly do it using JS or HTML because you do not have persistent storage. Meaning, once the client is closed all information is lost.

You're going to either need a database to keep track of how many people have visited your website (MySQL + PHP) or something along those lines

OR

You can use an external source such as google analytics which will do everything and more for you.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use persistent data storage. You can use a server side language like PHP to store data in the database or you use write to a file, then retrieve the data using AJAX requests to make it dynamic. As JavaScript is client side you can't do it.

**Simple Overview**

1. On load send request to `PHP` script to  increment counter.
2. Then in that `PHP` script return the number of views and manipulate the `DOM` using `JavaScript` and display it.

**Unique Visit Counter**

You'd get something like the visitors IP and check if they have visited the site before (you'd insert the IP in to a table) and compare the users IP with the ones in the table.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code in php:

```
<? 
Session_start(); 
$today = time(); 
$query="INSERT into logged_in (Today, SessionID, CurrentPage, BrowserType, IP) VALUES ('".$today."','".$_SESSION['sesid']."','".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."','".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."','".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."')"; 
$result = mysql_query($query); 
?>
```

but you need also logged_in table. I hope this help you!